# how to add a button to Windows CE 6 aygshell menu bar and link to a library function?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce, skinning, menubar, soft-keyboard

#### Dear fellow Windows CE developers,

I want to make a button available in the aygshell menu bar of Windows CE 6, that shows or hides the software input panel (SIP) of a Windows CE 6 r3 system.

My questions now are:

1. **What is the best way to add a soft keyboard button to an application specific toolbar?**
2. **How can I add a button programmatically (to an App specific** `aygshell` **toolbar) and link a library to it?**

---

*I have to accomplish this in Visual Studio 2005, Windows CE 6 r3 and the C++ BSP code.*

1. First approach was to find some settings for the `aygshell`, that make this automatically for me (since a software keyboard seems quite common), but i wasn't successful.
2. Second approach was to add a menu bar button and connect it to a library, that calls `SipShowIM`. I couldn't make it work, therefore I'd be happy if you guys could help me with good explained tutorials or links, better than the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499047%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) stuff. My steps were

   - in the graphical form development, I added a menu and there some menu items
   - in the source file to the form (but not the Dlg source) I added the library with the SIP functionality to the according method.

> void CaygshellbarApp::OnSipButton() {
>
> > > ...
> > >
> > > SipGetinfo( &info );
> > >
> > > bool visible = (info.fdwFlags & SIPF_ON);
> > >
> > > SipShowIM(visible? SIPF_ON : SIPF_OFF);
>
> }

---

I would be very glad for any good documentation links or some hints, how I can get this done. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499047%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) info was so far not enough.

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://www.krvarma.com/2008/08/creating-software-input-panel-sip-for-windows-mobile/) on how to create a SIP from scratch, it may help somehow. I used it a few years ago with good results.

Comment: thanks for the link! i believe since the SIP is a default extension of WinCE (included to platform builder) there should be a direct way to include it. 
my first guess would be registry, but so far i was not lucky...
any tips on the default activation maybe?